# SSAS. How to open FILE:// via Actions in Excel

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssas, mdx, olap

I have created an attribute called `LinkToImage` inside `Item` dimension. Attribute store paths to files in following:

```
file://\\localhost\dir\img1.jpg
file://\\localhost\dir\img2.jpg
and so on...
```

I've created an action via *Visual Studio 2013* in following:

```
MyCube.cube > Actions >
```

Name: `Link To Image`

Target type: `Attribute members`

Target object: `Item.Link To Image`

Action content Type: `URL`

Action expression: `[Item].[Link To Image].CURRENTMEMBER.NAME`

Additional properties Caption: `"Link To Image"`

In this case I got warning:

> The urls that do not begin with "http://" or "https://" are
>   considerend unsafe and will not be displayed by most applications

After deploying and exporting It to Excel In `Additional Actions` I see `No Actions Defined`

---

If I change Action Expression to: `"HTTP://" + [Item].[Link To Image].CURRENTMEMBER.NAME`

In Excel appears `Additional Actions` > `Link To Image`, but not working because It adding `HTTP://` protocol in front of path and It's not accesable in that way:

```
http://file://\\localhost\dir\img1.jpg
```

Have you ideas how to achieve that without adding `http://`?

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there is any way other than building a website to display those images and having your action link to the website. Excel only shows HTTP(S) actions not other types of URLs.

Refer to this whitepaper for the proof that Excel specifically only renders HTTP(S) type URL actions:
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=9982

Comment: Thanks for an answer... But If simple I paste following url to Excel: `file://\\localhost\dir\img1.jpg` It automatically converting url to Hyperlink and It's working, opening file.... So that's mean Excel supports `FILE://` protocol, just issue with Actions...

Comment: @Infinity I edited my answer with a link to some documentation proving file actions won't work. Yes it is just an issue with actions.

Comment: @Infinity if I have answered your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark.